# googlemapsapi returns status:INVALID_REQUEST and an empty JSon object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, google-maps-api-3

I am using node.js to develop firebase cloud functions. I need to connect to google maps api to get the distance between two Latlng points. I am making an https get request and receiving a response with a JSon object. The problem is that the received object is empty with a status: INVALID_REQUEST in most cases. However, in some rare cases it returns the desired value. I have tried the path and host of my request on the browser and the json object is retrieved successfully there. I do not know exactly where my problem is. Is it in the callback? the path? something else?
 I am giving my code and the output of it.

My code is :

```
function getStatusCode(options, callback) {

    https.get(options, function(http_res) {
        var data = "";
        console.log('inside the https request');
        http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
            console.log("I am reading the data");
            console.log(data);
            // callback(http_res.statusCode, data)
        });

        http_res.on("end", function () {
            console.log("I am in the ON_END listener");
            console.log('data contains: >> ' + data + ' I am in the ONEND listener')
            callback(http_res.statusCode, data)
        });
    });
}
```

and I am calling it as follows:

```
console.log('startingPoints ' + startingPoints);
    console.log('lat and lng are: '+lat+" , "+lng);
    var options = {
        host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
        path: '/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='+startingPoints+'&destinations='+lat+','+lng+'&key=MY_GOOGLEMAPSAPI_KEY',
        method: get
    };


    getStatusCode(options, function(statusCode, data){
        console.log('The status code is : '+statusCode);
        console.log('and data is : '+data);

        // parsing json object:
        jData = JSON.parse(data);
        rows = jData.rows;
        console.log('the length of the rows array is >> ' + rows.length + ', the length of the techs array is >> ' + techs.length);
        min = -1;

        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
            console.log('the array of techs + the equivalent values of the array of row >>' + techs[i] + ' and ' + rows[i].elements[0].distance.value);
            if( min < 0 || rows[i].elements[0].distance.value < rows[min].elements[0].distance.value)
                min = i;
            console.log('minimum distance tech in the loop; the id is >> ' + techs[min] + ", and the distance is >> " + rows[min].elements[0].distance.value);
        }
        console.log('the min value before return is >> ' + min);
```

and the retrieved json object is:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

any idea please,,

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. precisely, found my problem. The problem was not within google-map-api. It was with assignment of the starting_points variable.